# How to specify an existing database for django to use?

Tags: selenium

I think by default Django will create a new and empty test database to run the test cases. Is it possible to configure Django to use an existing database instead of creating a new one?

===

EDIT: The technologies:

- Language: Python
- Framework: Django
- Browser interaction: webdriver

Comment: What environment and language are you using?

Comment: @FDM : I'm using Python and Django.

Comment: Selenium doesn't normally use a database at all - how is it using one in your test setup?

Comment: @vincebowdren: I think I confused "selenium" and Django's test framework. You are right. Selenium itself doesn't use a database. However, because I'm new to selenium and I'm using it in a Django project, I didn't realize that I was actually talking about Django's test database.

Comment: @yaobin I've edited your question so it's now asking about Django, because that's what is responsible for the test db.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about configuring software rather than about SQA.

Comment: @KatePaulk Yeah, I think I should close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to set databases in *django* in general:

- [Django Settings: DATABASES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASES)

This is about [writing and using tests in *django*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/overview/) while this link is about using [unit tests in *django* and configure database settings for it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/internals/contributing/writing-code/unit-tests/#using-another-settings-module).

It's all from the django manual. I can't evaluate if it helps as I'm not into *django*.